suma en tiempo real con javascript
Por favor quisiera que me ayuden con los siguiente, tengo tres tipos de participantes (estudiantes, profesores, y administrativos) para una actividad y tengo que calcular el total de hombres y mujeres de cada tipo, además del total de hombres y mujeres en general.
Logré hacer el cálculo por filas con el siguiente código:


function suma_est(valor) {
    var total = 0;
    valor = parseInt(valor);
    total = document.getElementById('est_total').value;
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
    document.getElementById('est_total').value = total;
}
function suma_prof(valor) {
    var total = 0;
    valor = parseInt(valor);
    total = document.getElementById('prof_total').value;
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
    document.getElementById('prof_total').value = total;
}
function suma_adm(valor) {
    var total = 0;
    valor = parseInt(valor);
    total = document.getElementById('adm_total').value;
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
    document.getElementById('adm_total').value = total;}
<table width="52%" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="9%">Participantes</td>
      <td width="18%">Hombres</td>
      <td width="16%">Mujeres</td>
      <td width="57%">total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Estudiantes</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="est_h" id="est_h" value="0" onchange="suma_est(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="est_m" id="est_m" value="0" onchange="suma_est(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="est_total" id="est_total" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Profesores</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prof_h" id="prof_h" value="0" onchange="suma_prof(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prof_m" id="prof_m" value="0" onchange="suma_prof(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prof_total" id="prof_total" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Administrativos</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adm_h" id="adm_h" value="0" onchange="suma_adm(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adm_m" id="adm_m" value="0" onchange="suma_adm(this.value);"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="adm_total" id="adm_total" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>total</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total_h" id="total_h" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total_m" id="total_m" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total_final" id="total_final" readonly></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
</table> 



Pero en el caso de que el usuario borre un numero sale el valor NaN en el input.
¿Cómo podría llenar el input con 0 en caso de que el usuario borre algún dato?
Además, ¿Cómo podría realizar la suma de columnas y el total general?

Varias consideraciones:
1.- Si el input va a recibir solo números es preferible utilizar
<input type="number">

El cual cuenta con la propiedad valueAsNumber que devuelve siempre un Number sin necesidad de usar parseInt, excepto cuando es vacío donde devuelve NaN
2.- Para colocar un valor "deafult", puedes utilizar el operador ||, ejemplo:
const UnValor = input.valueAsNumber || 0;

Si lo que está a la izquierda del operador || (en este caso input.valueAsNumber) es falsy UnValor será el valor de la derecha (en este caso cero), de lo contrario tomará el valor de la izquierda
3.- Yo prefiero utilizar el evento input por sobre el evento change, el primero se ejecuta siempre que hay un cambio, en cambio el segundo se gatilla cuando pierde el foco (en el caso de los input). No obstante, para este caso se puede utilizar cualquiera
4.- Tu estas ingresando instrucciones, no estas programando. Si tu tabla crece a 100 filas vas a tener que crear 100 funciones y no es la idea.
Siempre que veas que una función es esencialmente la misma a la otra, es señal que la estas repitiendo, por ejemplo, tú tienes esto repetido 3 veces:
function suma_prof(valor) {
    var total = 0;
    valor = parseInt(valor);
    total = document.getElementById('prof_total').value;
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
    document.getElementById('prof_total').value = total;
}

//Luego otras 2 funciones iguales

Esto es básicamente una función:
function suma(valor,id) {
    valor = Number(valor);
    total = document.getElementById(id)?.value || 0;
    document.getElementById(id).value = total + valor;
}

Yo te propongo otra forma de hacer la suma, te vales de atributos data-* para indicar a cada celda el tipo de fila y columna que es, por ejemplo:
<input type="number" data-col="hombre" data-row="est" value="0">

Aquí se indica que la columna es de la categoría "hombre" y la fila es de categoría "est" (estudiante), y para los totales
<input type="number" data-total="prof" value="0" readonly>

data-total="prof indica que es un total para profesores. Entonces queda solo utilizar selectores para obtener los totales que necesitamos, teniendo en cuenta que cada vez que se modifica el input son 3 totales los que hay que actualizar:

Total de fila
Total de columna
Total General



document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(a=>a.addEventListener("input",oninput));

function oninput(ev){
  ev.target.valueAsNumber = ev.target.valueAsNumber || 0; // El cero por default
  const ds = ev.target.dataset;
  sumar("col",ds.col); //suma la columna
  sumar("row",ds.row); //suma la fila
  sumar("row","total"); //suma el total general
}

function sumar(tipo,valor){
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-${tipo}="${valor}"]`);
  let suma = Array.from(inputs).reduce((a,i)=>a + i.valueAsNumber,0);
  document.querySelector(`input[data-total="${valor}"]`).valueAsNumber = suma || 0;
}
<table width="52%" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="9%">Participantes</td>
      <td width="18%">Hombres</td>
      <td width="16%">Mujeres</td>
      <td width="57%">total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Estudiantes</td>
      <td><input type="number" data-col="hombre" data-row="est" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-col="mujer" data-row="est" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-total="est" value="0" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Profesores</td>
      <td><input type="number" data-col="hombre" data-row="prof" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-col="mujer" data-row="prof" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-total="prof" value="0" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Administrativos</td>
      <td><input id="algo" type="number" data-col="hombre" data-row="adm" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-col="mujer" data-row="adm" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-total="adm" value="0" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>total</td>
      <td><input type="number" data-row="total" data-total="hombre" data-row="total" value="0" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-row="total" data-total="mujer" data-row="total" value="0" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="number" data-total="total" value="0" readonly></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>




Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder. No tengo mucha experiencia programando y me está costando mucho poner solución a las cosas, gracias por ayudarme.

@LeX Un placer haber podido ayudarte, suerte con tu proyecto
